# How to dynamically configure servlet settings of non-embedded Jetty?

Tags: jetty

I have a non-embedded Jetty. I would like to dynamically configure a servlet's settings. Specifically, I want to change the default servlet's `resourceBase` setting.

In the `web.xml` file it's simply

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>resourceBase</param-name>
    <param-value>something</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

But how can I change this dynamically using code? And where do I have to put that code?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a webapp, and are using `WEB-INF/web.xml`, then the resourceBase is the webapp itself.

You cannot change that.

You can, however, make a NEW `DefaultServlet` entry, to serve other content from a different `url-pattern` (note: You cannot use `/` or `/*` for this new servlet's url-pattern), just define it as a new Servlet, with it's own name.